# How can I improve this PHP MySQL call?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update an older MySQL PHP method call but I end up calling the same SELECT call twice to achieve the same result.  Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the original:

```
function updateProbabilities()
{
    // first update the word count of each category
    $rs = $this->con->select("SELECT category_id, SUM(count) AS total FROM nb_wordfreqs WHERE 1 GROUP BY category_id");
    $total_words = 0;
    while (!$rs->EOF()) {
        $total_words += $rs->f('total');
        $rs->moveNext();
    }
    $rs->moveStart();
    if ($total_words == 0) {
        $this->con->execute("UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=0, probability=0 WHERE 1");
        return true;
    }
    while (!$rs->EOF()) {
        $proba = $rs->f('total')/$total_words;
        $this->con->execute("UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=".(int)$rs->f('total').",
                                    probability=".$proba."
                                    WHERE category_id = '".$rs->f('category_id')."'");
        $rs->moveNext();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is my version:

```
function updateProbabilities() {

    $sql = "SELECT category_id, SUM(count) AS total FROM nb_wordfreqs WHERE 1 GROUP BY category_id";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    $total_words = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $total_words += $row['total'];
    }

    if ($total_words >= 1) {

        $sql = "SELECT category_id, SUM(count) AS total FROM nb_wordfreqs WHERE 1 GROUP BY category_id";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            $proba = $row['total']/$total_words;

            $count = (int)$row['total'];

            $sql = "UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=".$count.",
                    probability=".$proba."
                    WHERE category_id = '".$row['category_id']."'";

            mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        }

    }
    else {

        $sql = "UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=0, probability=0 WHERE 1";
        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    }

    return true;
}
```

Do you see any way I can avoid this second duplicate SELECT call?

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: As @Barmar pointed out, replace the second $sql and $res lines by "mysql_data_seek($res, 0);". It should work.

Comment: And you can get rid of the "WHERE 1" in your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you run the query, add this to the while loop to store the results:

```
$rowarray[] = $row; // added to prevent running it twice
```

Then the second time it comes up, replace this:

```
$sql = "SELECT category_id, SUM(count) AS total FROM nb_wordfreqs WHERE 1 GROUP BY category_id";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

with this:

```
foreach ($rowarray as $row) {
```

ALSO: move away from mysql_ functions, as they are deprecated and will soon be removed from PHP. Change to a PDO or MySQLi. You're already upating the code, may as well make that change too.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql equivalent of `$rs->moveStart()` is:

```
mysql_data_seek($res, 0);
```

P.S. If you're rewriting into a new API, why are you using the deprecated mysql extension? You should use mysqli or PDO? They have similar methods for rewinding the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the first query to a unique variable, and re-use the results of that query.

```
function updateProbabilities() {

$sql = "SELECT category_id, SUM(count) AS total FROM nb_wordfreqs WHERE 1 GROUP BY category_id";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$total_words = 0;
$results = array();

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $total_words += $row1['total'];
    $results[] = $row1;
}

if ($total_words >= 1) {

    foreach ($results as $row2) {

        $proba = $row2['total']/$total_words;

        $count = (int)$row2['total'];

        $sql = "UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=".$count.",
                probability=".$proba."
                WHERE category_id = '".$row2['category_id']."'";

        mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    }

}
else {

    $sql = "UPDATE nb_categories SET word_count=0, probability=0 WHERE 1";
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
}

return true;
```

}

Comment: You're aware that your code only looks at the first row from the original query, right?

Comment: @DiMono: I don't see that, it's looping through the result set

Comment: @DiMono : You're code is using just the first row(­­$results = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);). Paul's code is looping through the whole query(while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)){...}). Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Comment: @DiMono: My bad ;) ... sorry!

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that bug.  I changed it so it reflects what I was initially trying to do, which is to only make the mysql call once, and do the rest in PHP.